# С++ как начертить график в консольном приложении?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, консоль, графика, gdi

У меня есть код, находящий значения конхоиды Никомеда, и я хотел бы реализовать отрисовку графика по точкам(параллельно с вычислением значений). Я пытался сделать отрисовку прямо в консоли, но в моей реализации график отрисовывается моментально и пропадает при первой перерисовке окна. Есть ли какие-то другие варианты отрисовать график? Я думаю о варианте открыть еще одно окно (WinForm) и отрисовать уже в нем, но не могу найти примера чего-то подобного...

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <clocale>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Conhoid(void) {
    float h = M_PI / 180,x,y,a = 20,r = 40;
    float f = -3;
    while (f <= 3) {
        x = a + r * cos(f);
        y = a * sin(f) / cos(f) + r * sin(f);
        printf("x = %f     y = %f\n",x,y);
        f += h;
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI Stream(LPVOID lparoun) {
    Conhoid();
    return 0;   
}

DWORD WINAPI DrawStream(LPVOID lparoun) {

        HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
        HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        float h = M_PI / 180, x, y, a = 20, r = 40;
        float f = -3;
        while (f <= 3) {
            x = a + r * cos(f);
            y = a * sin(f) / cos(f) + r * sin(f);
            SetPixel(hdc, 300+x, 50 + y, RGB(255, 255, 255));
            f += h;
        }
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
        std::cin.ignore();
        return 0;
    }

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");
    DWORD dwStream = 1;
    HANDLE hStream, drawStream;
    hStream = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Stream, &dwStream, 0, &dwStream);
    drawStream = CreateThread(NULL, 0, DrawStream, &dwStream, 0, &dwStream);
    if (hStream == NULL)
        printf("Поток не запущен\n");
    else {
        printf("Поток завершился\n");
        printf("\n");
        CloseHandle(hStream);
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну можно еще рисовать в битмап или используя что-то типа gnuplot

Comment: Рисуйте график в файле звездочками, как делали во времена алфавитно-цифровых дисплеев. Потом просматривайте а Блокноте. :-)

Comment: > Рисуйте график в файле звездочками, как делали во времена алфавитно-цифровых дисплеев. - ну конечно, последние 25 лет развития компьютеров нужны были именно для этого... Хотя иногда задумываешься: нарисовать график функции на ZX Spectrum или БК-0010 было немного попроще, чем сейчас на среднем офиснмо компьютере

Comment: Выплёвывайте данные в gnuplot. Он — сила, и это решение кроссплатформенно.

Answer (score 2):

То, что вы рисуете напрямую в окне консоли, затирается стандартным обработчиком отрисовки conhost при следующем обновлении окна (как при выводе нового текста в консоль, так и при изменении, например, размеров ее окна). Переопределить этот обработчик нельзя, но можно отобразить свое окно поверх консоли, как показано в примере ниже. Кроме того, код рисования графика в вопросе рисует график по отдельным точкам, я переделал его с SetPixel на MoveTo/LineTo, чтобы он выглядел непрерывным.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <clocale>
#include <iostream>

WCHAR szTitle[] = L"Conhoid";
WCHAR szWindowClass[] = L"ConhoidWndClass";

//координаты окна
const int WND_X = 300;
const int WND_Y = 50;
const int WND_W = 400;
const int WND_H = 400;

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
DWORD WINAPI Draw(HDC hdc);

DWORD WINAPI Run(LPVOID lpThreadParameter)
{   
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    HWND hCon = GetConsoleWindow();
    RECT rc;
    MSG msg;

    MyRegisterClass(hInstance); //инициализация класса окна 
    GetWindowRect(hCon, &rc); //получаем положение окна консоли     

    //создаем окно
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_BORDER, rc.left + WND_X, rc.top + WND_Y, WND_W, WND_H, hCon,
        nullptr, hInstance, nullptr); 

    SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, 0); //убираем строку заголовка

    if (hWnd == nullptr)
    {
        printf("Error CreateWindow\n");
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd); 

    //запуск цикла обработки сообщений
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc;
    switch (message)
    {   
    case WM_PAINT:

        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        Draw(hdc);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    break;  
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

void Conhoid(void) {
    float h = M_PI / 180, x, y, a = 20, r = 40;
    float f = -3;
    while (f <= 3) {
        x = a + r * cos(f);
        y = a * sin(f) / cos(f) + r * sin(f);
        printf("x = %f     y = %f\n", x, y);
        f += h;
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI Stream(LPVOID lparoun) {
    Conhoid();
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI Draw(HDC hdc) {        

    float h = M_PI / 180, x, y, a = 20, r = 40;
    float x0, y0;
    float f = -3;

    x = a + r * cos(f);
    y = a * sin(f) / cos(f) + r * sin(f);
    x0 = x;
    y0 = y;
    SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(WHITE_PEN));
    MoveToEx(hdc, 300 + x, 50 + y, nullptr);

    while (f <= 3) {
        x = a + r * cos(f);
        y = a * sin(f) / cos(f) + r * sin(f);

        if (abs(y - y0) < 1000) {
            LineTo(hdc, 300 + x, 50 + y);
        }
        else {
            MoveToEx(hdc, 300 + x, 50 + y, nullptr);
        }

        f += h;
        x0 = x; y0 = y;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");
    DWORD dwStream = 1;
    HANDLE hStream, drawStream;
    hStream = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Stream, &dwStream, 0, &dwStream);
    drawStream = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Run, &dwStream, 0, &dwStream);
    if (hStream == NULL)
        printf("Поток не запущен\n");
    else {
        printf("Поток завершился\n");
        printf("\n");
        CloseHandle(hStream);
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: console graph]

Answer (score 0):

Используйте SetConsoleCursorPosition(..) для установки курсора в консоли на необходимые координаты.
Затем выводите символ, обозначающий линию, например '*'.

Comment: @Zoom В стародавние времена в таких случаях рисовали псевдографикой на принтере. Сейчас вы можете, например, сохранить в файле данные для отрисовки графика, а затем вызвать из консольного приложения другой exe-файл   (  system("start app.exe")  )   для отрисовки графики по исходным данным из файла в новом окне  (WinForm). Но почему бы не сделать всю программу приложением WinForm?

Comment: Исходный вопрос был про отрисовку графика в консоли. Я не могу предложить иной реализации кроме как использования вышеописанной функции. Если игнорировать это условие то ваше предложение можно назвать удачным :)

Comment: @Zoom Не сомневаюсь, что вы найдёте ответ на исходный вопрос. Просто нас так учили, что 50% успеха зависит от правильной постановки задачи. Иногда бывает полезно взглянуть на проблему чуть иначе, под другим углом.